# How to exit from the container after executing one script inside it

Tags: docker

`docker exec -it --user oracle cxo /bin/sh -c "perl /tmp/add.pl;exit"`

Update idcs test mode true to /application-optional.properties

File updated!!

Note: Above cmd is not exiting from the docker container and hangs there.

Answer (score 0):

you do not need to put exit at the end of the command if the script reached to end  and exit then all you need to not allocate pseudo-TTY,

```
docker exec --user oracle cxo /bin/sh -c "perl /tmp/add.pl"
```

But make you sure `perl /tmp/add.pl` this script exit.

[docker-exec](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/)